# Is there an easy way to access an app bundle file from a gradle task?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

You can easily access your app's apk file by doing something like

```
android.applicationVariants[0].outputs[0].outputFile
```

but that doesn't seem to work for an app bundle file. Is there a built in way to do this or do I have to generate the file path based on the flavor & build type?

Comment: did you find any solution for above requirement  ?

Comment: No, I had to manually generate the file path.

Comment: I got the same question and haven't found any solution :(